Android Media3 "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing implementation to handle one of the COMMAND_SEEK_*"
I am trying to implement a text to speech reader using Android TTS and Media3.
This is a lot of text separated by the dot, as TTS does not support content with more than 4000 characters in a single reading. There is no problem in that regard, the reading is done correctly, but if I try to skip by pressing the seek button or on the progress bar the application fails throwing the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing implementation to handle one
of the COMMAND_SEEK_*
at androidx.media3.common.SimpleBasePlayer.handleSeek(SimpleBasePlayer.java:3366)
at androidx.media3.common.SimpleBasePlayer.seekTo(SimpleBasePlayer.java:2366)
at androidx.media3.common.BasePlayer.seekToCurrentItem(BasePlayer.java:481)
at androidx.media3.common.BasePlayer.seekToOffset(BasePlayer.java:492)
at androidx.media3.common.BasePlayer.seekBack(BasePlayer.java:142)
at androidx.media3.ui.PlayerControlView$ComponentListener.onClick(PlayerControlView.java:1892)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7432)
at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28810)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

The error is this line in the SimpleBasePlayer file:
/* pendingOperation= */ handleSeek(mediaItemIndex, positionMs, seekCommand),

How can I fix this error?
This is my code:
TTS
@UnstableApi
class TtsPlayerCompose(
    looper: Looper?, context: Context?,
    text: StringBuilder,
    splitRegex: String,
    private var mProgressListener: (Int, Int) -> Unit

)  : SimpleBasePlayer(looper!!), OnInitListener {
    private val mTexts: Array<String>
    private val mTts: TextToSpeech
    private var mTextProgress = 0
    private var mIsPlaying = false
    private var state = State.Builder()
        .setAvailableCommands(

            Player.Commands.Builder().addAll(
                COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE,
                COMMAND_STOP,
                COMMAND_SEEK_BACK,
                COMMAND_SEEK_FORWARD,
                COMMAND_SET_SHUFFLE_MODE,
                COMMAND_GET_CURRENT_MEDIA_ITEM,
                COMMAND_GET_METADATA
            ).build()
        )
        .setPlayWhenReady(false, PLAY_WHEN_READY_CHANGE_REASON_USER_REQUEST)
        //.setAudioAttributes(PlaybackService.Companion.getDEFAULT_AUDIO_ATTRIBUTES())
        .setPlaylist(listOf<MediaItemData>(MediaItemData.Builder("test").build()))
        .setPlaylistMetadata(
            MediaMetadata.Builder().setMediaType(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_PLAYLIST)
                .setTitle("TTS test").build()
        )
        .setCurrentMediaItemIndex(0)
        .build()

    init {
        mTexts = text.split(splitRegex.toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
        mTts = TextToSpeech(context, this)
        mTts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(object : UtteranceProgressListener() {
            override fun onDone(utteranceId: String) {
                if (!mIsPlaying || mTextProgress == mTexts.size) return
                ++mTextProgress
                speakText()
            }

            override fun onStart(utteranceId: String) {
                updatePlaybackState(STATE_READY, true)
            }
            @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
            override fun onError(utteranceId: String) {
                //onError(utteranceId);
            }
        })
    }

    private fun speakText() {
        if (mTextProgress >= mTexts.size) return
        //API 21+
        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putInt(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
        for (name in mTexts) {
            //mTts.speak(mTexts[mTextProgress], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, bundle, "TTS_ID")
            mTts.speak(name, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, bundle, "TTS_ID")

        }
    }

    fun start() {
        mIsPlaying = true
        speakText()
    }
    
    fun resume() {
        mIsPlaying = false
        mTts.stop()
        start()
        updateProgress(mTextProgress, mTexts.size)
    }
    
    override fun getState(): State {
        return state
    }

    private fun updatePlaybackState(playbackState: Int, playWhenReady: Boolean) {
        val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
        mainHandler.post {
            state = state.buildUpon()
                .setPlaybackState(playbackState)
                .setPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady, PLAY_WHEN_READY_CHANGE_REASON_USER_REQUEST)
                .build()
            invalidateState()
        }
    }

    override fun handleSetPlayWhenReady(playWhenReady: Boolean): ListenableFuture<*> {
        if (playWhenReady) {
            val locSpanish = Locale("spa", "ESP")
            mTts.setLanguage(locSpanish)
            speakText()
        } else {
            mTts.stop()
        }
        return Futures.immediateVoidFuture()
    }

    override fun handleRelease(): ListenableFuture<*> {
        mTts.stop()
        mTts.shutdown()
        return Futures.immediateVoidFuture()
    }

    override fun handleStop(): ListenableFuture<*> {
        mTts.stop()
        return Futures.immediateVoidFuture()
    }

    override fun handleSetShuffleModeEnabled(shuffleModeEnabled: Boolean): ListenableFuture<*> {
        return Futures.immediateVoidFuture()
    }

    private fun updateProgress(current: Int, max: Int) {
        mProgressListener.invoke(current, max)
    }

    fun changeProgress(progress: Int) {
        mTextProgress = progress
        if (!mIsPlaying) return
        pause()
        start()
    }

    override fun onInit(status: Int) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            val locSpanish = Locale("spa", "ESP")
            val result = mTts.setLanguage(locSpanish)
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                return
            }
            changeProgress(1)
        }
    }

    fun close() {
        mTts.stop()
        mTts.shutdown()
    }
}

ExoPlayerView
@UnstableApi
@Composable
fun ExoPlayerView(text: StringBuilder) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var sliderMaxValue by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(100f) }
    val ttsPlayer = TtsPlayerCompose(Looper.getMainLooper(), context, text, Constants.SEPARADOR){ current: Int, max: Int ->
    sliderMaxValue = max.toFloat()}

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        onDispose {
            ttsPlayer.release()
        }
    }

    // Use AndroidView to embed an Android View (PlayerView) into Compose
    AndroidView(
        factory = { ctx ->
            PlayerView(ctx).apply {
                player = ttsPlayer
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
    )
}

Service
open class DemoPlaybackService : MediaLibraryService() {

    private lateinit var mediaLibrarySession: MediaLibrarySession

    companion object {
        private const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 123
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "demo_session_notification_channel_id"
    }

    open fun getSingleTopActivity(): PendingIntent? = null

    open fun getBackStackedActivity(): PendingIntent? = null

    protected open fun createLibrarySessionCallback(): MediaLibrarySession.Callback {
        return DemoMediaLibrarySessionCallback(this)
    }

    @OptIn(UnstableApi::class) 
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        initializeSessionAndPlayer()
        setListener(MediaSessionServiceListener())
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: ControllerInfo): MediaLibrarySession {
        return mediaLibrarySession
    }
    @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
    override fun onDestroy() {
        getBackStackedActivity()?.let { mediaLibrarySession.setSessionActivity(it) }
        mediaLibrarySession.release()
        mediaLibrarySession.player.release()
        clearListener()
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
    private fun initializeSessionAndPlayer() {
        val player = TtsPlayer(Looper.getMainLooper(), this, "")
        mediaLibrarySession =
            MediaLibrarySession.Builder(this, player, createLibrarySessionCallback())
                .also { builder -> getSingleTopActivity()?.let { builder.setSessionActivity(it) } }
                .build()
    }

    @OptIn(UnstableApi::class)
    private inner class MediaSessionServiceListener : Listener {

        override fun onForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException() {
            if (
                Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 33 &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                // Notification permission is required but not granted
                return
            }
            val notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this@DemoPlaybackService)
            ensureNotificationChannel(notificationManagerCompat)
            val builder =
                NotificationCompat.Builder(this@DemoPlaybackService, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_help)
                    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.lbl_nona))
                    .setStyle(
                        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.lbl_nona))
                    )
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .also { builder -> getBackStackedActivity()?.let { builder.setContentIntent(it) } }
            notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
        }
    }

    private fun ensureNotificationChannel(notificationManagerCompat: NotificationManagerCompat) {
        if (
            notificationManagerCompat.getNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID) != null
        ) {
            return
        }

        val channel =
            NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                getString(R.string.lbl_mixto),
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT,
            )
        notificationManagerCompat.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}

Edit
Apparently I need to override the handleSeek method, according to this comment on Github. I found an example of implementing this method here but I can't get it to work.
Making a test, I write this method in TTSPlayerCompose:
override fun handleSeek(
    mediaItemIndex: Int,
    positionMs: Long,
    seekCommand: Int
): ListenableFuture<*> {
    /*val compositionPlayerInternal: CompositionPlayerInternal =
        checkStateNotNull(this.compositionPlayerInternal)
    compositionPlayerInternal.startSeek(positionMs)
    for (i in 0 until players.size()) {
        players.get(i).seekTo(positionMs)
    }
    compositionPlayerInternal.endSeek()*/
    return Futures.immediateVoidFuture()
}

By placing a breakpoint on the return line, the code stops there when clicking on the forward button, the variablepositionMs has the value 15000 and the variable seekCommand has the value 12. My problem is that I don't know what code to write to make the audio advance or rewind according to those values. I also can't find a way to make the progress bar advance as the text to speech is being read.
If there is a better way to make Android TTS and Media3 work together, it would be welcome.
